# internal interface *less* accessible than an internal protected constructor?

Tags: c#, internal, protected

I have an interface and an abstract base class defined in the same assembly:

**IFoo.cs:**

```
internal interface IFoo { ... }
```

**Base.cs:**

```
public abstract class Base
{
    internal protected Base(IFoo foo) { ... }
}
```

This generates the following compiler error:

```
CS0051: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'IFoo' is less
        accessible than method 'Base.Base(IFoo)'
```

If I make the Base class constructor internal-only, the error goes away. Since the class is abstract, maybe adding protected to the accessibility doesn't accomplish anything...

Still, I don't understand the error. MSDN defines 'protected internal' as

> "Access is limited to the current assembly or types derived from the
>   containing class"

How is the internal interface IFoo *less* accessible than an internal protected constructor?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defined 'protected internal' as (emphasis from original):

> The protected internal accessibility level means protected OR
>   internal, not protected AND internal. In other words, a protected
>   internal member can be accessed from any class in the same assembly,
>   including derived classes. To limit accessibility to only derived
>   classes in the same assembly, declare the class itself internal, and
>   declare its members as protected.

So in other words, types from outside the current assembly that derive from `Base` would have access to `Base(IFoo foo)` but they wouldn't have access to IFoo, since it is internal. Thus the error.